# Getting higher resolution Facebook profile picture from javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

as the title suggests, I'm looking for a way to get a higher resolution profile picture from the FB graph API.

So far, this is what I have:

FB.api('/me?fields=id,first_name,about,location,gender,cover,picture,friendlists,friends, function(e) { ....

From several admittedly perfunctory Google searches, I've only come up w/ the following:

FB.api('/'+id+'/picture?type=large&width=300&height=300'

However, adding "?type=large", etc., didn't seem to do the trick. Any ideas????

Answer (score 2):

Remove `type=large` since you have already defined sizes via `width` and `height`. Also change `width` and `height` to calls on picture.

`FB.api('/me?fields=id,picture.width(300).height(300)')`

The highest "resolution" will depend on the original photo uploaded.

So one wouldn't be able to request a 1500 x 1500 photo when the user uploaded a 640 x 640 photo.